# Scala Probabilistic Priority Queue - dequeue with probability by priority

Tags: scala, data-structures, priority-queue

I have a priority queue, which holds several tasks, each task with a numeric non-unique priority, as follows:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class Task(val name: String, val priority: Int) {
  override def toString = s"Task(name=$name, priority=$priority)"
}

val task_a = new Task("a", 5)
val task_b = new Task("b", 1)
val task_c = new Task("c", 5)

val pq: mutable.PriorityQueue[Task] =
    new mutable.PriorityQueue()(Ordering.by(_.priority))

pq.enqueue(task_a)
pq.enqueue(task_b)
pq.enqueue(task_c)
```

I want to get the next task:

```
pq.dequeue()
```

But this way, I'll always get back **task a**, even though there's also **task c** with the same priority.

1. How to get one of the items with the highest priority randomly? That is to get either task a or task c, with 50/50 chance.
2. How to get any of the items randomly, with probability according to priority? That is to get 45% task a, 10% task b, and 45% task c.

Comment: you could order priorities based on a Roulette wheel selection algorithm

Comment: I don't know Scala, but in many of the languages I do know I'd implement a custom comparator for the priorities which randomized the choice as a secondary ordering criterion when the priorities would otherwise be considered equal.

Comment: This looks interesting https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/kafka/HEAD/core/src/main/scala/kafka/utils/timer/TimingWheel.scala

Comment: Depending on how accurate you want it to be, and how large you queue is, `Ordering.by(Random.nextDouble*_.priorty)` may be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good starting point:

```
abstract class ProbPriorityQueue[V] {
  protected type K
  protected implicit def ord: Ordering[K]
  protected val impl: SortedMap[K, Set[V]]
  protected val priority: V => K

  def isEmpty: Boolean = impl.isEmpty

  def dequeue: Option[(V, ProbPriorityQueue[V])] = {
    if (isEmpty) {
      None
    } else {
      // I wish Scala allowed us to collapse these operations...
      val k = impl.lastKey
      val s = impl(k)

      val v = s.head
      val s2 = s - v

      val impl2 = if (s2.isEmpty)
        impl - k
      else
        impl.updated(k, s2)

      Some((v, ProbPriorityQueue.create(impl2, priority)))
    }
  }
}

object ProbPriorityQueue {

  def apply[K: Ordering, V](vs: V*)(priority: V => K): ProbPriorityQueue = {
    val impl = vs.foldLeft(SortedMap[K, Set[V]]()) {
      case (acc, v) =>
        val k = priority(v)

        acc get k map { s => acc.updated(k, s + v) } getOrElse (acc + (k -> Set(v)))
    }

    create(impl, priority)
  }

  private def create[K0:, V](impl0: SortedMap[K0, Set[V]], priority0: V => K0)(implicit ord0: Ordering[K0]): ProbPriorityQueue[V] =
    new ProbPriorityQueue[V] {
      type K = K0
      def ord = ord0
      val impl = impl0
      val priority = priority0
    }
}
```

I didn't implement the `select` function, which would produce a value with weighted probability, but that shouldn't be too hard to do.  In order to implement that function, you will need an additional mapping function (similar to `priority`) which has type `K => Double`, where `Double` is the probability weight attached to a particular key bucket.  This makes everything somewhat messier, so it didn't seem worth bothering about.

Also this seems like a remarkably specific set of requirements.  You're either doing a very interested bit of distributed scheduling, or homework.